# arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute with UPDATE and OUTPUT

Tags: arcpy, sql-server

Is there a way to get OUTPUT through arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute? Whatever I do I get only True. When running UPDATE through MS SQL Server Management Studio I get OBJECTID of all updated features (rows):

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_MINIMUM = 0 OUTPUT INSERTED.OBJECTID WHERE MY_MINIMUM < 5
DB result type: <type 'bool'>
DB result: True
```

Comment: No, I don't think you can. It's certainly a question for Tech Support.